# Unknown grandfather

Tags: dna

Is it possible to know if my grandfather is the same person as my cousins grandfather thru DNA? My grandmother and my cousin's grandmother are sisters. All of these grandparents are dead.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are referring to the same cousin, and your grandmothers are sisters, then, that must mean you are technically second cousins. Your most recent common ancestor (MRCA) would be the parents of those two sisters, two of the 8 (max) total great grandparents you have. But in short, yes, absolutely, DNA will be able to help you uncover how exactly you and your "cousin" are related. And what would be especially helpful is having the DNA for additional living relatives, such as any of your and/or your cousin's parents, etc.